# Kolmogorov–Smirnov interpreting results between two signals

Tags: python, statistics

I want to test if two signals have the same distribution, but i am not sure how to interpret the results i get using Kolmogorov-Smirnov.

```
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp

#Result 1
ks_2samp(X, Y)
Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.9609858416360776, pvalue=0.0)

#Result 2
ks_2samp(X, Z)
Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.22699528054535922, pvalue=0.0)

#Result 3
ks_2samp(X, A)
Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.0628631358154169, pvalue=2.2469873930819826e-82)

#Result 4
ks_2samp(X, B)
Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.0060199265862611595, pvalue=0.3524473755058249)
```

in Result 1 the p_value is lower than 0,05 so i can reject the null hypothesis and this means that they don't have the same distribution?

in Result 2 and 3 this is the same?

looking at Result 4, the p_value is higher than 0,05 which means that they are coming from the same distribution?

As far as i know:
The D statistic is the absolute max distance of the two samples. The closer this number is to 0 the more likely it is that the two samples were drawn from the same distribution.

The p-value returned by the k-s test has the same interpretation as other p-values. You reject the null hypothesis that the two samples were drawn from the same distribution if the p-value is less than your significance level.
How do I know my significance Level?

How can I say if according to the D and p_value if they are from the same distribution or not?

Thanks, R

Comment: This would have been better on http://stats.stackexchange.com I suppose, though actually I think you should read a bit more about what a p-value is during the time you are waiting for an answer. Hint: the p-value is the smallest value of the significance level such that the null is rejected.

Comment: I just read: "One practice that has been particularly criticized is accepting the alternative hypothesis for any p-value nominally less than .05 without other supporting evidence." on wikipedia. Which means my assumption is wrong?

Comment: Wikipedia is right, you cannot prove (i.e. be 100% sure) that that the two signals have the same distribution by just looking at a p-value. _But_ the p-value gives a _hint_ how likely it is to be true. It's complicated, as you found. You can silently cheat and think about it this way: the p-value indicates how likely it was that the null (signals are from same distribution) is true. By the way, the k-s test is a _goodness-of-fit_ test, maybe that helps when googling.

Comment: A very low p-value (like the first three) means that you can reject the null with a very low type 1 error, so you can reject while being very confident that you don't reject when the null is true.

Comment: Suppose the null is true, with a significance level of 0.05, 5 out of 100 times you do the test with a new sample you will get a p-value _lower_ than 0.05: you will reject the null _when actually it's true_. This is the type 1 error you make.